# Regex for addresses in sparse/bad data

Tags: python, regex, search

I have a long file which was mangled by OCR/conversion and looks like this in general...

```
-------------JOE-LTO-N   ------TN---370-80 -----------------------                                                                                                              
"00900006202                 26808      NAME, IDA BELLE &  BILLY               7621 RIDGEWOOD RD GOODLETTSVILLE 37072               $298.07"                                                                                                                
"NAME, IDA BELLE 7621RIDGEWOOD RD"                                                                                                              
GOODLITTSVILLE                                                                                                              
"NAME, BILLY"                                                                                                               
7621RIDGEWOOD RD                                                                                                                
TN            37072 ....
```

...and I am trying to extract names/addresses using regex.

I need to extract all data matching the form LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME and also data matching the form STREETNUMBER TEXT ZIPCODE.

So far I have:

```
import re
import csv
exA = "ex-a.csv"
namelist = []
addlist = []
with open(exA, 'r') as exhibitA:
    lines = csv.reader(exhibitA, delimiter=",")
    namesearch = re.compile('([A-Z]+\w+, (\w*)')
    addsearch = re.compile('\d+(.*)\d{5}')
    for l in lines:
        names = namesearch.findall(str(l))
        namelist.append(names)
        adds = addsearch.findall(str(l))
        addlist.append(adds)
print(addlist)
```

But I'm having no success extracting this information. At best it's partial and inaccurate. It doesn't need to be perfect, but I'd like to get most of the data into a better form. Can anyone help?

Comment: You say that you're getting partial and inaccurate data, but the first regex doesn't even compile.

Comment: Name Regex: `(?<=NAME,\s)([A-Za-z&\s]*?)(?=\"|\s+\d)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/knkvRC/1)

Answer (score 0):

Name Regex: `(?<=NAME,\s)([A-Za-z&\s]*?)(?=\"|\s+\d)`[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/knkvRC/1/)

Address Regex: `\d+\s?[A-Za-z][\w\s]+[\w]+(?:\d{5})?` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/knkvRC/2/)